# How can I pass object to Eric Martin's OSX modal?

Tags: jquery, macos, modal-dialog, simplemodal

From my jsp I have something like

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>${event.name}</td>
    <td>${event.type}</td>
    <td>${event.dateString}</td>
    <td>${event.virtualMachine.name}</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="osx">View event</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to pass the event object to the modal content such that It will display more information regarding the event object. That said, I'm hoping someone could help me find way to display

Event
    
    
        
             
        
        Event Name
        ${event.name}
        
        
        Event Type
        ${event.type}
        
        
        Event Description
        ${event.description}
        
        
        Date Time
        ${event.dateString}

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do it, what have you tried? If it were me, I'd get the A element in the click function and then work with it's parent and parent's siblings to get the values you want.